# Android Picasso - Clear cache but image remains

Tags: java, android, caching, memory, picasso

So at certain times I need to clear the Picasso cache within my application, however when I clear it, the image is the same. If the image URL changes, then it pulls the new image but if the image url is the same, then the old image remains.

Can anyone help me clear the cache so that the image is removed?

This is how I set Picasso up:

```
Cache picassoCache = new LruCache(MEMORY_CACHE_SIZE);
        picassoCacheClearer = new PicassoCacheClearerImpl(picassoCache);
        picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(context.getCacheDir(), IMAGE_CACHE_SIZE))
                .memoryCache(picassoCache)
                .build();
```

and then try and clear it by:

```
cache.clear();
```

Below is the code which actually loads the image:

```
picasso.load(carouselAction.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                .into(viewHolder.plistImageView);
```

I can see that the Invalidate() method is now deprecated, so what else can i do?

Comment: It's probably not a good practice to change image and leave same url.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović - totally agree with you, however I do not have control over the image url, thats another team.

Comment: It looks like you are clearing your held memory cache, but OkHttp will still load images from OkHttp's disk Cache. There are a few ways to get around this. As stated below, you could force a different key to be used. You could also use an OkHttp Interceptor to force certain requests to use the network. Picasso also has a `networkPolicy` which can tell `OkHttpDownloader`'s Request not to read from the disk.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem and I used this hacky method to get around it. To force it to refresh i would just change the url adding a version tag to it. This is used commonly in web development to make sure things aren't used from the cache.

For example i would load an image from example.com/mypic.png?version=1234
and since the url is different it wouldn't load it from cache.

```
String versionTag = "?version=" + new Date().getTime();
picasso.load(carouselAction.getImageUrl() + versionTag)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                .into(viewHolder.plistImageView);
```

Comment: when I do what you suggested below:

private void bindData(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final CarouselAction carouselAction) {
        String versionTag = "?version=" + new Date().getTime();
        picasso.load(carouselAction.getImageUrl() + versionTag)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                .into(viewHolder.plistImageView);
    }

It keeps requesting for the same images and not using the cache at all. is getTime() the correct usage here?

Comment: Well you only do that when you want a new image you don't do it all the time

Answer (score 0):

So found out what the issue was. Turns out for this carousel it was using a different instance of Picasso.

I also had to extend OkHttpDownloader to expose the getClient() method in order to get the cache to delete.

I realised it was a different instance of Picasso by enabling the indicators which can be done by setting the following in the builder

```
.indicatorsEnabled(true);
```